# How to show a transparent layout when a button is pressed in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I m unable to show a overlay when a button inside the a function() is pressed. Please help me.

Comment: Can we see a code snippet please?

Comment: @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new 
     Stack(
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      children: <Widget>[
        ExercisePage(handleAnswer()),
       
       overlayShouldBeVisible==true? 
       new CorrectWrongOverlay(isCorrect) : new Container() ,
      ],
    ); 
  }